# Why might a large stack size cause a delay on first Win API call?

Tags: c++, winapi, stack

I have used the File New C++ app Wizard in Visual Studio 2015 to create a simple 'Hello World' Window app. When linked with the default stack size, it launches instantly.

When linked with a stack reserve size of 1073741824, the app hangs for tens of minutes before becoming responsive again.

Increasing the stack size gradually from the default will also increase the delay gradually.

In another executable I have used EditBin.exe to change the stack from the 1mb default to the 1gb value above and it also hangs in the same way and becomes responsive later on. Changing it back causes everything to run smoothly again.

I think I have tracked it down to the first WIN32 API call. It does not seem to be the particular call itself but the fact that a new DLL is being loaded and inheriting the stack from the executable. CPU and memory stay idle during this operation. I think it is compounded by the exe being 32 bit and running on 64 bit.

This is a repro for a large application which uses a very big stack so I'd like to figure out what could be happening in general when that first API call is executed. Is memory being zeroed out?

When debugging in Visual Studio, the hang happens here but I think this is misleading.

```
// Main message loop:
while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
{
```

**Update:**
 Stack size: Not my code, but the original is a Fortran app which does a lot of calcs for particle physics and that size was set originally. I can't change it without understanding what is going on first.

Release mode: All compiled for release mode, 32 bit.

Memory usage: I don't actually see any memory assigned or CPU activity though. From what I understand, the stack reserve is just a reserve to call upon it's not actively assigned at app start. The app uses the same memory at both stack levels on startup.

Single threaded: Just the example app out of File New.

Loading DLL: In debugging the original Fortran code (of which this is a repro) the issue happened when the DLL was called. Checked with a WinHelp call and a Window Create call. I assumed the DLL was being loaded in process at this point.

**Update2:**
 I understand I need to fix the code, this is part of investigating it. It also happens with this C++ code. What I am after specifically, is what is happening when the WIN API is called and the UI becomes unresponsive? That might provide a clue and a workaround until the 40-50 year old Fortran code is re-worked and upgraded to 64 bit.

Comment: Well, the operating system will need to suddenly find a gig of RAM to map, on the first page fault. It'll probably need to evict some processes from memory, and dump them to a swap file, before resuming execution of this very, very, rude process.

Comment: (1) The DLL is loaded when the application starts, not when you first call a method it in. (2) A DLL doesn't 'inherit the stack from the executable'. A DLL doesn't have a stack, and neither does an executable. *Threads* have stacks. (3) You don't need a stack that big.

Comment: 1073741824 bytes is not 512 MB. It's 1 GB. And the fact, that your application *"hangs"* at a `GetMessage` call is normal behavior, for a high-traffic, blocking call. If you randomly break into any given Windows application, it'll usually be waiting for messages to arrive.

Comment: by the way, why do you need such a big stack in a message-driven windows app?

Comment: And since EJP pointed it out: The stack is owned by a thread. And every thread gets the default stack size. So if you have more than one thread (and pretty much every application creates threads), the system needs to find 1 GB of memory for each one. How many threads do you have?

Comment: Not sure, but have you tried turning off the randomization of base addresses? I think it's on by default with Visual C++. Anyway, big stack requirement implies something fishy about the code.

Comment: Are you using debug mode ? Visual studio usually clears the stack with 'sentinel' values to detect accessing unassigned variables. Maybe this is done all at once in microsoft's debug crt.

Comment: 1) 1gb, yes, big, but it's particle physics, the s/w is older than me (late 60's) and the original maintainer has retired. It could be fixed but I want to find out what is going on. 2) I got DLL load wrong, updated question.

Comment: You'll need to fix the Fortran code to make more sane use of stack. You can't expect a process to function with 1GB default stack size. That doesn't end well. If you can't fix the Fortran code at least execute it in a thread that you create with a stack size that you define when you create it. And stick to the default 1MB stack size for your process. Then at least only one thread in your process is clobbered. Make sure you create that thread on startup though when address space is easy to come by. You'll want 64 bit code too.

Comment: I just wonder how the program was getting 1GB of stack when it ran in the late 60s.

Comment: Obviously, it's grown and that was tacked on to solve a problem.

Comment: *What I am after specifically, is what is happening [...] might provide a clue and a workaround* - it might be something to do with the various anti-hacking measures incorporated into modern versions of Windows.  The only way to tell for sure would be to step into the API to see what it's actually doing.  (Perhaps try running the FORTRAN app in a VM running as old a version of Windows as you can get your hands on?  Or on Linux, for that matter?)